# How can I override SaveChanges method in RavenDB?

Tags: ravendb

Is there a way to modify behavior of `SaveChanges` method in RavenDB? When I use EF Core, I always override that method in my DbContext to provide additional logic, such as setting audit fields (`CreatedBy`, `ModifiedBy` etc.). In RavenDB however, I do not inherit from `DocumentSession` anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checkout the [OnBeforeStore](https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/5.2/Csharp/client-api/session/how-to/subscribe-to-events) event 
 in: https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/5.2/Csharp/client-api/session/how-to/subscribe-to-events.

You can perform custom actions on any entity right before it is stored on the server.